# Spring SAML and user simulation

Tags: spring, spring-security, simulation, saml, spring-saml

We use spring SAML and SAML protocol itself for authentication purposes. In our application we have the following group of users:

- admin users
- super users
- users

We would like to allow admin users to simulate super users and users as well as super users to simulate users. By simulation I mean a process when one user can open application like another user and all functionality, menu items and actions avalailable for the last one will be available for the user who is in simulation mode. 
For example I can have admin user Mirko_Admin who would like to check how shopping card works for a user Cain. What he can do:

1. login in the application
2. find Cain user and start simulating the user
3. so Mirco_Admin will be using the application like Can user does

It is quite easy to implement for one application, but when we have at least two aplications using SSO(in our case SAML based) it becomes another type of challenge. 
Do you have any ideas how simulation mode can be implemented for multiply application using SAML and SAML identity provider? I can give an example explaing what we need.

1. admin users logs in
2. finds a user and starts simulation process for this user opens
3. another application connected to SAML identity provider
4. simulation mode is also active as well as for all other applications 
   connected to the same identity provider